# Reindex dataframe based on substring in a column

Tags: pandas, python-3.8

I have a dataframe `df1` as follows:

```
Col1    Val
asd     1
pqr     2
rtyq    3
dffg    4
```

I have another dataframe `df2` as follows:

```
Col1    Col2
22rtyq  c4
asd2c   c1
1pqr    c2
pqr67f  c3
56as    c5
```

I am trying to get the following:

```
Col1    Col2    Val
22rtyq  c4      3
asd2c   c1      1
1pqr    c2      2
pqr67f  c3      2
56as    c5      NaN
```

In the above `asd` from `df1` is present in `df2` as `asd2` so it gets the value of 1 from `df1`.
`rtyq` from `df1` is present in df2 as `22rtyq` so it gets the value of 3 from `df1`

I am not sure how to proceed with the above.

Comment: I have modified the problem statement above so that you can see it is not just lining the index problem.

Comment: Is it possible if you could remove number in `Col1` from `df2`? Therefore both dataframes get identical key and you could use `pd.merge()` to combine them

Comment: no there can be characters present also like in `asd2c`. I just made that modification.

Answer (score 3):

We can try extract matched `df1` `Col1` from `df2` `Col1` then `map` the corresponding `df1` `Val` to `df2`

```py
df2['Val'] = (df2['Col1'].str.extract(r'(' + '|'.join(df1['Col1']) + r')')[0]
              .map(df1.set_index('Col1')['Val']))
```

```
print(df2)

     Col1 Col2   Val
0  22rtyq   c4   3.0
1    asd2   c1   1.0
2    1pqr   c2   2.0
3   pqr67   c3   2.0
4    56as   c5   NaN
```